# Getting Nonetype() <= int()

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code generates a random weighted number is

however, I'm getting an error

```
output expected .05 output received .06
```

The problem is with eval_autograder(n) but how can In fix this to show the histogram?

Comment: Are you using Python 2.7 or Python 3.x? You've used both tags but they have very different behaviour. You must also be calling this function somewhere but you don't show that code. More information is required.

Comment: @MatthewTrevor plz see changed. I'm using Python 3

Comment: The traceback should also show you which line the error is occurring at, can you include that as well?

Comment: @MatthewTrevor I'm trying to create a histogram with 4 bars (going from smallest to largest) for eval_autograder.  This not working

Comment: @MatthewTrevor basically the only info I have is when I run it through an external system test() (i don't have that code) it just gives me the error unorderable types: NoneType() <= int() and global name 'plt' is not defined

Comment: @MatthewTrevor don't understand why I'm getting Nonetype for autograder() because I always get a integer returned.  Is it because of my eval_autograder(n) function?

Comment: I can imagine it being `n` is passed `None` somewhere plus `plt` not being defined

Comment: @Darkhogg yeah that's what I see as the problem.  But how do I fix eval_autograder(n) ? I'm trying to create the histogram

Comment: @user3486852 I can't know what `plt` is. With `n` the problem resides at the call site, not the declaration site. And I don't see it called anywhere... :/

Comment: @Darkhogg basically I'm trying to graph the histogram.  So four bars with the height going from smallest to largest.  I need to completely change around my function but don't know where to start

Comment: @MatthewTrevor I'm getting .06 instead of .05 for the final probability.  I changed the last elif to else but got this new error

Comment: Please don't update your question as you make changes, it invalidates the solutions you've been provided. Make a change, test it fixes the problem listed, then isolate the new issue and start a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the source of None:

```
>>> 100 in range(95,100)
False
>>>
```

Comment: but how do I show the histogram? I need 4 bars going from smallest (0,69) to highest (90,100)

Comment: also now I'm gettting the error Output Expected: D 0.05 Output received: D 0.06

Answer (score 0):

There's a mismatch between the range of your random numbers and the ranges you're testing in your `if` and `elif` statements. `random.randint` generates a random number between its arguments, **including both of the endpoints**. On the other hand, a `range` contains its start value, but not its end value.

When `randint` generated the number 100, it would not be detected by your `if`s, so you'd fall off the bottom of the function and Python would return `None`. This is the why you were getting an error later in your code.

As an quick fix, use `random.randrange` rather than `random.randint`. This will generate a random number in the range 0-99, which is what your code checks for.

A further improvement might be to not use `range` at all, since you can simply do less-than comparisons to get the same effect:

```
def autograder():
    i = randrange(0,100) # changed function here, generates numbers 0-99
    if i < 45:
        return randint(90,100)
    elif i < 80:
        return randint(80,89)
    elif i < 95:
        return randint(70,79)
    else: # this catches i < 100, but we don't need to specify it exactly
        return randint(0,69)
```

I left the return values as they were, but you might also want to change the first `randint` to `randrange` (or just adjust the bounds) if you don't want the return values to include both `0` and `100`.

Comment: how would I fix the histogram though? Like how would I show the histogram?

Comment: That sounds like a different question than what you'd originally asked. I'm afraid I don't know enough about Python's plotting libraries to be able to help with that part of your issue.